# How do I segue from a nested collectionView cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I have a `collectionView` used for scrolling between pages, inside of one of these full page cells I have another `collectionView` with cells. How do I perform a segue when one of the cells inside of the inner most collectionView is tapped.

Comment: did my answer help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a delegate on the cells with collection view, that will need to be notified when a particular cell is selected:

```
protocol CollectionCellDelegate: class {
    func selectedItem()
}

class CollectionCell: UITableViewCell {

    weak var delegate: CollectionCellDelegate?

    // ...

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.delegate?.selectedItem()
    }
}
```

And in the `TableViewController` you will have to implement that delegate to perform segue from it (you have to perform segue from `UIViewController` subclass, but the `UITableViewCell` is not subclassing it, that's why you need the delegate pattern).

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController, CollectionCellDelegate {

    // ...

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionCell
        // set its delegate to self
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    }

    func selectedItem() {
        // here you can perform segue
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "mySegue", sender: self)
    }

}
```

I haven't passed any argument to the delegate, but you can of course use arguments to pass any information that you need for the segue (e.g., the id of the collection cell that was selected, etc.).

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer it works, it was really helpful. Out of curiosity why do we have to add a delegate for this to work and why is there a check necessary `collectionView == self.innerCollectionView`. It works very well thank you very much for your detailed answer. It was very helpful.

Comment: @user372382 to be honest I have NO idea why I have put there that check :D.. I believe you can remove that, I have updated the answer

Comment: In any event thank you so much for your answer, I was stuck for days on this thank you for all of your help.

Answer (score 0):

When you tap on an item in collectionView, the following delegate method will be called (if you wired up everything properly) `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)`... notice that the first param is collectionView itself.

Depending on how you set it up...

if you have two collectionViews within one UIViewController then you can do..

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
             didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  if collectionView == self.innerCollectionView {
     // performSegue...
  }
}
```

if you have two view controllers, one for outer and another for inner.. then you can create use delegate pattern to let the outer know which item got selected, and segue using that info.

Comment: When ever I try to call `performSegue` inside of `didSelectItemAt` of the inner most collectionView I receive the error "Use of unresolved identifier performSegue"

Comment: How is your view controllers setup?

Comment: Also in storyboard.. did you setup segue with the name to the destination controller?

Comment: I have a MainViewController with `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource` protocols and 3 cells where each cell acts as a view and then a collectionViewCell inside of one of those three page cells with the same protocols which holds another `collectionView`.